# How to create a profile interface like instagram and pass data through tableviews [Swift]

Tags: swift, tableview, collectionview

I'm trying to create a ViewController like instagram profile, pretty complicated, here's what I've done.
I put inside a table view cell a collectionView and inside this collectionViewCell I put a tableView, here's the scheme.
Now how can I pass data through mainViewController to the last tableView inside collectionViewCell?
I've tried use notification but, is there another way?[image]
Is the right way to made a profile like instagram or not?
Thank you

Comment: Honestly, I believe this is the most complicated way to do this. If I were you I'd google how to use a compositional layout https://medium.com/better-programming/ios-13-compositional-layouts-in-collectionview-90a574b410b8 ... Anyway, to answer your question; you can use a protocol / delegate pattern or even pass the data using a database. The way you are trying to do this currently will get real messy, real fast.

Comment: Yes, I've try use collectionview layout but how can I made the scroll horizzontal view for my photos and photos where i'm tagged, like instagram?

Comment: You will need to implement orthogonal scrolling — https://dev.to/kevinmaarek/replicating-the-appstore-s-collectionviewlayout-orthogonal-in-swift-5-42je

Comment: Ok thank you, now I try.

Comment: But, in this way I've to put the table view inside collection view cell again